# Simplify completely connected directed networkx graph

Tags: neural-network, networkx, directed-graph

Is there an algorithm in `networkx` for dealing with completely (or very highly) connected directed graphs (DiGraphs)?

I have a network of flows which are all non-zero but vary hugely in magnitude. I want to visualise the network, but I need a sensible way of finding an underlying structure where, ideally, each node would have a maximum of one in- and one out-flow.

N.B.
This is the concept of 'nodal flows', as described by [Nystuen and Dacy (1961)](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/45977/10110_2005_Article_BF01969070.pdf?sequence=1) but I don't know what the modern equivalent is called!

Comment: So, in your case, does an outgoing (incoming) flow of a specific node correspond to an outgoing (incoming) edge of that node?

Comment: @f_ficarola Yes, I've used 'flow' when I meant 'edge'.

Comment: So, if I understood well, you are just interested in discovering all those nodes having a maximum of one in- and one out-edge, right? I mean, what you want is a list of nodes having that feature?

Comment: Nope! I'm looking to summarise a highly-connected network into a simpler structure like, for example, a minimum spanning tree. The key phrase in the question is 'underlying structure'. I want to *extract* something from a mess of edges.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I don't think there's something similar in networkx (at least I've never found it), but it shouldn't be too hard to implement. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can do a good comparison of the nodes with the max indegree/outdegree of the network.  You could visualize the network as 3 nodes.  The 2 with the largest indegree/outdegree and another node for "the rest". Then you can put it in a sankey diagram e.g. http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/sankey_demo_rankine.html